# How do I create a directory within the current working directory, in Java

Tags: java, filesystems

What is the most succinct way to create a directory called "Foo" underneath the current working directory of my Java application (if it does not already exist)?

Or, a slightly different angle: What is the Java equivalent of `Directory.CreateDirectory("Foo")` in .NET?

Comment: You asked a question and immediately posted your own answer ?

Comment: -1. Seems very weird to post a question and an answer. Stack Overflow is not a microphone for you to lecture from.

Comment: +1. Is fine to post your own question and answer. Helps the community and useful for future reference. If people disagree with your answer then they can provide a better one. A *quick* search on Meta SO seems to agree that this is fine.

Comment: Following up my previous comment : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not

Comment: +1 Also right on top in http://stackoverflow.com/faq. `It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.`

Comment: I stand corrected! -1 removed.

Comment: ...or would be, except my 'vote is too old'. (Oops.) @Daniel, if you edit the question, which will let me revote, I'll clear my -1...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The java.io package does not have a `Directory` class, but you can use the `mkdir()` method on the `File` class instead:

```
(new File("Foo")).mkdir()
```

Note that `mkdir()` has two separate failure modes:

1. "If a security manager exists and its `checkWrite()` method does not permit the named directory to be created" then a `SecurityException` will be thrown.
2. If the operation fails for another reason, `mkdir()` will return false. (More specifically, it will return true **if and only if** the directory was created.)

Point 1 is ok — if you don't have permission, throw. Point 2 is a little sub-optimal for three reasons:

1. You need to inspect the boolean result from this method. If you ignore the result the operation could silently fail.
2. If you get a false return you have no idea why the operation failed, which makes it difficult to recover, or formulate a meaningful error message.
3. The strict "if and only if" wording of the contract also means that the method returns false if the directory already exists.

> Aside: Contrast Point 3 with the
>   behaviour of the .NET
>   `Directory.CreateDirectory()` which
>   does nothing if the directory exists.
>   This kind of makes sense — "create a
>   directory"; "ok, the directory is
>   created". Does it matter if it was
>   created now or earlier; by this
>   process or another? If you really
>   cared about that wouldn't you be asking a different
>   question: "Does this directory exist?"

The next caveat is that `mkdir()` will not create more than one directory at a time. For my simple example of a directory named "Foo" this is fine; however, if you wanted to create a directory called Bar within the directory Foo (i.e. to create the directory "Foo/Bar") you must remember to use the `mkdirs()` method instead.

So to work around all of these caveats, you can employ a helper method such as the following:

```
public static File createDirectory(String directoryPath) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(directoryPath);
    if (dir.exists()) {
        return dir;
    }
    if (dir.mkdirs()) {
        return dir;
    }
    throw new IOException("Failed to create directory '" + dir.getAbsolutePath() + "' for an unknown reason.");
}
```

Comment: You asked a question and immediately posted your own answer ?

Comment: Seen that before, the idea is that the user who posts the question+answer combination wants to present a thorough answer to some question which may seem simple in a context which will direct those people who do not yet know how to do it to his own answer. Perfectly acceptable in my opinion although a bit confusing.

Comment: Ah, so now I know how the "Blog" part of Stackoverflow's vision (http://sstatic.net/so/Img/stackoverflow-venn-diagram.png) comes from :)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a slightly more concise form of your `createDirectory` method:

```
File f = new File(xyz);
if (!f.exists() && !f.mkdirs()) throw new IOException("Could not create directory " + f);
```

It might also be worthwhile to check if `f` exists but is not a directory.