# Add a directory in current path

Tags: java, path

Given *absolute path* of a *file* is something like this:

```
    myFile.getAbsolutePath();
    //C:\myapp\etc\templates\file1.ftl
```

I want to copy the file to

```
    //C:\myapp\etc\templates\customized\file1.ftl
```

Please note only *templates* folder and the name of file(*file1.ftl*) are known and the program has no idea on other parts of the full path at all; I want to insert a new foldername after *templates*

My question is what is the proper way to get the current path and add a folder name in the folder hierarchy.
At the moment I can use the `replace()` function of `String` class or I can insert the new foldername by building a new `path` by using `Path.iterator()` but I'm not sure will they work in all cases and on all OSs

**EDIT:** This question marked as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554252/how-do-i-create-a-directory-within-the-current-working-directory-in-java) but it's not, the linked question is about creating a directory in current directory.

Comment: `new File(new File(myFile.getParentFile(), "customized"), myFile.getName())` or `myFile.toPath().getParent().resolve("customized").resolve(myFile.getName())`

Comment: @VGR Thanks for the solution
Actually this question is not duplicated, the linked question is about creating directory in current directory.

Comment: If your parent folder is always same, you may want to consider using relative target path